# Numpy Hstack ValueError

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

im writing some color detection for tetris, but when I try to run the code I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hampus.ramsten\Desktop\Detection - test.py", line 49, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("virtual_board", np.hstack([resize, output]))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in hstack
  File "C:\Users\hampus.ramsten\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\shape_base.py", line 346, in hstack
    return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 1)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in concatenate
ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has size 168 and the array at index 1 has size 1080
```

guessing it comes from here,but I don't know:

```
boundaries = (104, 120, 164)
boundaries1 = (106, 122, 166)

for (boundaries) in boundaries:
    lower = np.array(boundaries, dtype = "uint8")
    upper = np.array(boundaries1, dtype = "uint8")

    board_mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)
    output = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask = board_mask)

    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(board_mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    print(contours)
    contours = sorted(contours, key=lambda x: cv2.contourArea(x), reverse=True)

    resize = ResizeWithAspectRatio(image, width=300)
    cv2.imshow("virtual_board", np.hstack([resize, output]))
```

What is the problem?

Comment: The `shape` of the 2 inputs arrays doesn't match. What's `resize.shape` and `output.shape`?  You might need to (RE)read what `hstack` expects from its inputs.  Do you understand what we mean by `shape`?

Comment: I'm really new, so no, what is that?

Comment: So you are using some else's code - but with your own data (or set of images)?

Comment: yes, that's it, "https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/04/opencv-python-color-detection/" and "https://pysource.com/2019/12/07/detect-tetris-board-and-tetrominoes-python-plays-tetris-p-3/"

Answer (score 0):

Your error message precisely indicates the cause:

```
ValueError: ...
but along dimension 0
the array at index 0 has size 168 and
the array at index 1 has size 1080
```

The error occurred actually in *np.hstack*, because
you attempt to stack horizontally arrays with different numbers of rows.

Comment: And how do I fix that?

Comment: If you stack horizontally 2 arrays, then they must have the same number of rows.
Maybe *ResizeWithAspectRatio* generates "too much compressed" output.
Another solution, allowing at least perform *hstack* is to append to the
"smaller" array as many rows as is needed to align their row numbers.
Another issue is what should be the value in the added rows (I don't know, my knowledge of image processing is **very** limited).